# How do you suppress logging for one particular action?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to suppress Rails logging for one particular actions (it's polled by javascript every 2 seconds and I don't need all that output). How do I accomplish this? Rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look here: [How to silence the call to a rails controller's action all together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403073/how-to-silence-the-call-to-a-rails-controllers-action-all-together) and here: [How can I disable logging in Ruby on Rails on a per-action basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196828/how-can-i-disable-logging-in-ruby-on-rails-on-a-per-action-basis)
2. You can look deeper into Rack to optimize your application. If javascript poll returns simple data it will fit perfectly for you